# Converting factors with character names to numerics (after import from an .sav file)

Tags: r, type-conversion

So after I've imported a data.set via memsci (which worked very nicely btw! :)), I now have the problem that almost all of the data is converted to (non-ordered) factors, but the levels are not 1,2,3,4,5 (which is what it should be for calculations) but rather "fully agree" down to "don't agree at all".

This leads to the problem that I can't use `as.numeric(levels(f))[f]` to convert the factor into numerics.

To get import my data I used this:

```
data <- as.data.set(spss.system.file("data.sav"))
dat <- as.data.frame(data)
```

However: The informations seems to be there.

```
str(var1)

Factor w/ 5 levels "don't agree at all",..: NA 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...

labels(dat$var1)
  [1] "1"   "2"   "3"   "4"   "5"   "6"   "7"   "8"   "9"   "10"  "11"  "12" 
 [13] "13"  "14"  "15"  "16"  "17"  "18"  "19"  "20"  "21"  "22"  "23"  "24"

levels(dat$var1)
[1] "do not agree at all" ". ."              ". . ."           
[4] ". . . ."          "fully agree"
```

Where are the values stored? I've tried `labels(var1)` and just `var1`, but I neither works. However: Using `as.numeric(var1)` gives me the information I need, BUT I don't think one should apply this as stated in the R help for factors. Also after using `dat[,1:ncol(dat)] <- lapply(dat[,1:ncol(dat)], function(x) as.numeric(x))`
the variable is still being considered a factor and behaves exactly the same as before.

Edit: Reproducible example thanks to @jakub

```
var1 <- factor(c(1,2,3,4,5,5,4,3,2,1), 
               levels = as.character(1:5),
               labels = c("Fully agree", "....", "...", "..", "Do not agree at all"))
```

Comment: please post a reproducible example (with code) so others can reproduce your problem

Comment: try `as.numeric(var1)` it should work

Comment: I'm not actually able to post a reproducible example. From my understanding the code for one would look like this:
`var1 <- factor(c(1,2,3,4,5,5,4,3,2,1), 
        levels = c("Fully agree", "....", "...", "..", "Do not agree at all"),
        labels = as.character(1:10))`
Which is not a command that works. But to me the data looks like it has been created this way.

Comment: In your example, switch `labels` and `levels`; also, `as.character(1:10)` should be  `as.character(1:5)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say:

> `as.numeric(var1)` gives me the information I need, BUT I don't think one should apply this as stated in the R help for factors

If you refer to:

> In particular, `as.numeric` applied to a factor is meaningless, and may happen by implicit coercion.

then you are most likely confusing two issues. You either want the *labels*, or you want the *levels*.

If you have numerical values that happen to be labels of a factor, then indeed you have to convert to numeric using `as.numeric(levels(f))[f]`. An example:

```
var1 <- factor(c(1,2,3,1), 
               labels = c("123", "5", "-11"),
               levels = as.character(1:3))
levels(var1)
# [1] "123" "5"   "-11"
as.numeric(var1)
# [1] 1 2 3 1  #this indeed does not make much sense - the values are lost!
as.numeric(levels(var1))[var1]
#[1] 123   5 -11 123
```

**But in your case, this does not apply,** because (if I understood correctly), you don't want the labels, but the underlying integers. For you, it makes sense that `Fully agree` means `1`. In such case, `as.numeric(var1)` is fine.

Comment: You're exactly on spot with what you said **however** for some reason `var1 <- as.numeric(var1)`. Works great on the example that looks like my data.set. **But** if I use it on my dataset var1 is displayed as numeric in the workspace (so far so good) but `is.numeric(var1)` is still `FALSE`, while `is.factor(var1)` is `TRUE`. I don't really get why and I assumed that is why as.numeric should not be used in this case aswell. Could it be related to the conversion from a data.set into a data.frame? That seems odd though.

Comment: I am not familiar with `data.set`. But what happens if you call `dat$var1 = as.numeric(dat$var1)` and then `class(dat$var1)` ?

Comment: I've found my mistake. I have used `attach(dat)` before. Which lead to no change when using `str(var1)` to confirm that is has become numeric. After rerunning `attach(dat)` or not using it, it is indeed displayed as numeric correctly. Is this odd behavior on `attach()`'s side or have I been using I wrong all the time? o_o
Thanks for the great help anyways, I've marked your answer as correct of course!

Comment: Honestly, when I hear `attach` I scream in pain and run away. Perhaps other people have found a way how to use `attach` efficiently, but to me `attach` makes it difficult to keep track of my code, because I have to keep in mind constantly that somewhere up the line I have called attach on something, and it makes me very prone to making mistakes that are hard to spot.